# getStringArray by string text

Tags: android, arrays, string

I´ve got the following code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(countries2.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Europe));


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(countries2.this, ListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CountryName", listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Now I want to set the `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Europe)` to `getStringArray(R.array.stringname)`
So I just want to dynamically set the array which the app should get (for example: Europe, Africa, USA, ...)

```
String stringname = "Europe" //or Africa, USA,...
```

How can I dynamically set the array which should be get?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do

Comment: I try to not preset the getStringArray(R.array.Europe); I try to set the getStringArray  dynamically, based on user interaction. So I have different arrays (Europe, Africa, USA,...) and want to display them dynamically when the app is running. It should display in the Listview. The array contains items with more informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`getIdentifier`**

Try this,

```
String stringname = "Europe";
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(stringname , "array",
            this.packageName);


ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(countries2.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        getResources().getStringArray(resourceId));
```

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Rather passing getStringArray(R.array.Europe) returned array directly in the adapter, Create String array reference outside. And on the basis of user interaction check what user has selected and in conditional statement get the string array and refer to the reference passed array in adapter and then notify the adapter. Hope that answer the question. Change your code with below code to initialized adapter

```
  String [] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Europe);

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(countries2.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            array
            );
```

And when user changes the option on the behalf of that user interaction repopulate your array and notify the adapter

Comment: how can I do this? I´m new at Android Dev.